# Animated container with gradient background color

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

How can I change the background color of a container from bottom to top?
When I use gradients, I don't like the effect.
I build a second container, but it's not dynamic.

```
class MyCustomContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color progressColor;
  final double progress;
  final double size;

  const MyCustomContainer({
    Key key,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.grey,
    this.progressColor = Colors.red,
    @required this.progress,
    @required this.size,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyCustomContainerState createState() => _MyCustomContainerState();
}

class _MyCustomContainerState extends State<MyCustomContainer> {
  double _progress;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _progress = widget.progress;
  }

  onPaint() {
    setState(() {
      if (_progress == 0) {
        _progress = 1;
      } else {
        _progress = 0;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: widget.size,
          width: widget.size,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: widget.backgroundColor,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: widget.size * 0.3,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: widget.size * 0.7,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  curve: Curves.easeInOutExpo,
                  height: widget.size * _progress,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Container(
                      height: widget.size * 0.3,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: widget.size * 0.7,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
              Text('asdas'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => onPaint(),
        child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want that transition, over an over again changing the colors of the two containers.
If the states changes, do the transition and in the next iteration, change colors and play again.
This is the animation to emulate.
[Video animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EN_TlgP8oaTNYiEAqJg9wEn1O8AslnCM/view?usp=sharing)

Any idea how?

Comment: *"I want that transition, over an over again changing the colors of the two containers."* - this is what `AnimatedContainer` is used for (or `TweenAnimationBuilder` for animating custom properties)

Answer (score 1):

There is something like `ColorTween` class ( https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/ColorTween-class.html )

You can google some tutorial how to do that, there is plenty of it.

**Update**

In case that you want to hover one container with another and then in time reaviling it I would put both `Containers` into the `Stack widget` and set initial height of one of `Containers` to 0 and just animate height.

**Update 2**

To be able to control animation you should use `AnimationController` and you could forget about using `AnimatedContainer`.

As I experimented in the ways how to reset `AnimatedContainer`, there is some trick to do that. The key is to set callback `onEnd` and inside to change duration to `1 milisecond`, restore `_progress` to initial value and `setState` , Before starting animation again you will need to set proper duration.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _progress = 0;
  }

  onPaint() {
    setState(() {
      dynamicDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 2000);
      if (_progress == 1) {
        _progress = 0;
      } else {
        _progress = 1;
      }
    });
  }
  
  void resetAnim(){
    
    setState((){
      dynamicDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 1);
      _progress = 0;
    });
    
  }
```

**Update 3**

to be able to loop it you would have to use async function to wait till restoration to point A has ended

```
  void resetAnim() async {
    
    setState((){
      dynamicDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 1);
      _progress = 0;
     
    });
    
     await new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds : 50));
      
     
     setState(() {
      dynamicDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 2000);
      
        _progress = 1;
     
    });
```

It all looks kinda tricky/dirty so maybe it would be worth learning to use `AnimationController` and/or `TweenAnimationBuilder`

Comment: I have, but tween color migrates from color to other using an effect that I don't want. I wan't to change from bottom to top like progress bar do.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to just hover one container with another, setting height of the first to 0 and then raising its height to 100% and sticking container to bottom ?

Comment: I got 2 containers, with diferent color in a stack. I wan't to change the color of both from bottom to top. The effect that I want is the same as the example provide. The problem in the example is that I wan't that effect just bottom to top every time a state change.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to play animation from point A to B always, not from A to B and in next iteration B to A ?

Comment: Sorry for the late. This is what i'm looking for. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EN_TlgP8oaTNYiEAqJg9wEn1O8AslnCM/view?usp=sharing). I know that I need controllers, the example is to represent the desire effect.

Comment: I dont have access so

Comment: Sorry about that. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EN_TlgP8oaTNYiEAqJg9wEn1O8AslnCM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: the code I updated kinda is doing that but with one element. You could do it with 3 elements with help of some `counter` variable to know which one should be animated after "await new Future..."  Anyway I think its all up in my answer. I won't be explaining AnimationController or TweenAnimationBuilder as there is plenty of sources out there and after all, this post is already too big.

Comment: @user3046679 I just want to mention that `dynamicDuration` needs to be putted in `AnimatedContainer`'s duration attribute. I hope you make it helps